# How do I resize the background behind an image?

Tags: css, background, resize

The image changes sizes and positions on different pages and I want to be able to only have the color behind the photo be about 10px on all sides.

```
.wp-caption, .wp-caption-dd {
text-align: left;
margin: 0 auto 15px;
padding 10px;
background: rgb(245, 222, 179);
border: 0px;
  }
```

and you can look at a few different pictures on

http://www.metnews.org/features/pretty-lights-new-album-a-two-disc-electronic-masterpiece/
http://www.metnews.org/sports/lansfords-departure-leaves-questions/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS

```
.wp-caption{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Or set the background color to the image instead of the container

```
wp-caption img{
    background: rgb(245, 222, 179);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
.wp-caption, .wp-caption-dd {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
  padding 10px;
  background: red;
  border: 0px;
  display:block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vVmuR/2/)